# File upload, change name

Tags: php, file

I have a file upload script which works fine, however it currently saves the document under the original file name, I want to rename this on upload, ideally adding an ID number before it (from GET variable, below)

```
$employee=$_GET["id"];
```

The file upload script, where the name comes from is below:

```
$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
```

How can I add the ID number before the name upon saving?

Comment: By concatenating your ID similar to how you're concatenating `$key` before it now

Comment: Could you show me an example? As i'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Well first off, what's `$key` in your code? In general you'd do something like `$file_name = $myID.$key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file_name = $employee . $key . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
```

Should suffice -- But it is considered very bad practice to act on any user-provided data without first sanitizing & validating it.

Check out: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Untrusted_data for more information.

You should first ensure that the $_GET['id'] variable fits the expected pattern, and is a valid employee ID -- at the very least!